# How to manipulate URL inside ajax call?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, moodle

I am trying to trigger an ajax call on change of a dropdown menu(at client_script.php). The ajax call will send some values to server_script.php and it will change a div section of the client_script.php. The problem is the server script is kept in a local directory such as blocks/latestgrades/server_script.php. When the ajax call is done the url becomes the address of the server_script.php prepended by

```
 http://localhost/umoodle
```

Which is quite ok, because the server_script/php file location is such.
But when I hover around the other pages, the onchange triggeres the ajax call which tries to find the server_script.php on that location but prepended by

```
http://localhost/umoodle/<something_i_dont_want_here>/
```

How to alter the url to cut that place I dont want and then do an ajax call with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the ajax url is an absolute url (beginning with a forward slash) so that it is formed from the root instead of relative to the current page. For example: (url: '/umoodle')

Comment: HOLY MOLY:@:@:@...Thanks a lot. Didn't think it would be so trivial..:))

Comment: It's always the little things we often overlook. Glad I could help.